# How to change object class and associated functions

Tags: python, class, methods

If I have 2 classes A and B, is there a way I can make an instance of class A "jump" to class B and vice versa?

I'd like to write a function for class A that, when called, essentially makes that instance of class A get reinitialized as a class B object and continue its execution as a normal instance of class B would. I'd like to make a similar function for class B. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like code smell. Can you post your classes and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't like it, but I can't think of another way. I haven't created the files yet, but I'm building an autonomous capture the flag game. There are two agents on each team, a defensive and offensive one, and when one dies, I want their roles to switch. This seemed like the solution

Comment: It's a smell. A role is a _property_ of an object, which should is assigned at run time. Allowed behaviors for different roles can be managed with object composition, or roll-your-own function tables. This really isn't a good use for `class` IMHO. But others may disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, yes.

```
>>> class C: pass
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> type(c)
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> c.__class__
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class D: pass
... 
>>> c.__class__ = D
>>> c.__class__
<class '__main__.D'>
>>> type(c)
<class '__main__.D'>
```

I used Python 3.6.3 to do this.

Want to see jumping in action? Check this out:

```
>>> class C:
...   def speak(self):
...     return "I'm a C"
... 
>>> class D:
...   def shout(self):
...     return "I'M A D"
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c.speak()
"I'm a C"
>>> c.__class__ = D
>>> c.shout()
"I'M A D"
```

Python we love you, uh, I guess so.... This is weird. But cool, yeah?

How about trying an experiment on your own to see how you can preserve attributes from the original class! It's neat.